# Can't change decimal spectator default on server?

Tags: web-config, number-formatting, globalization, culture, region

I moved my site server and the new server uses comma instead of period when using decimals.

Locally i set my machine to use comma so that i could work out a code fix.

I added `<globalization culture="af-ZA" uiCulture="af-ZA" />` to my web.config and found that it then apply's the period to separate decimals, which is what i was looking for.

When i place `<globalization culture="af-ZA" uiCulture="af-ZA" />` onto my site web.config hosted on new server it does not change the decimal separator to period, it says as comma?

Could the server force a format standard that is stopping me from changing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

this way, the server will ignore the settings, and will use the "default" value.
in your case, it will use comma.